# Why do I get Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-: when trying to create an API gateway resource using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to create and [AWS API gateway resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method) with subdirectories from the root with Terraform?

When doing

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "MyDemoResource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "/will/this/work"
}
```

I get the error:

```
aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource: 1 error occurred: aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource: Error creating API Gateway Resource: BadRequestException: Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-: or a valid greedy path variable and curly braces at the beginning and the end."
```

I've found this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21048)  and a few others like it. I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design with a workaround.

Additionally, If I create this manually in the AWS console and then import it, the full path appears in the attribute `path` properly but not in the input `path_part`.

```
"aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource": {
                    "type": "aws_api_gateway_resource",
                    "depends_on": [],
                    "primary": {
                        "id": "foo",
                        "attributes": {
                            "id": "foo",
                            "parent_id": "foo",
                            **"path": "/will/this/work"**,
                            **"path_part": "work"**,
                            "rest_api_id": "foo"
                        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `path_part` is the [**last** path segment of an API Gateway resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_resource#argument-reference), not the *full* path. This mirrors the tree-like structure that you see in the AWS Console.

The full path is exported, yes, but is not taken in as an argument. That's why you have the full path in the imported Terraform state as `path` and the last path segment - `work` - as the `path_part`.

**Currently, you're not passing the last path segment; you're passing the full path.**

What you need to do is specify 3 different `aws_api_gateway_resource` each for the different parts of the path segment, with the parent IDs correctly specified to create the structure you need:

1. `will` with the parent ID of `aws_api_gateway_rest_api.{REST-API-NAME}.root_resource_id`
2. `this` with the parent ID of `aws_api_gateway_resource.will.id`
3. `work` with the parent ID of `aws_api_gateway_resource.this.id`

---

Visual representation:

```
MyAPI
├─ /will
│  ├─ /this
│  │  ├─ /work
```

Comment: unfortunately `/will` tosses the error `Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-:` also

Comment: No no - I did `/will` to demonstrate the actual path, you need to just use `will` on its own

Comment: You don't need a workaround - Terraform automatically adds in the "/', I've explained that the multiple parts need to be assembled together; this is how the API Gateway works. Use `will` and that will yield a path of `/will` but the path part must be without `/` as they are automatically inserted. It's a part of the path, not the path